# Получить уровень группировки Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ado

Имеется Excel-таблица с одной колонкой примерно следующего вида (в квадратных скобках указано что чем является):

1. Ванна `[наименование]`
   1.1 Комфорт `[характеристика]`
   1.1.1 Белая `[свойство]`
   1.1.2 Серая `[свойство]`

Могу ли я получить уровень группировки, осуществляя запрос к таблице с использованием ADO?

Сама задача выглядит так:

Необходимо получать данные из таблиц Excel без участия данной программы. Было решено использовать для этих целей ADO. У большинства таблиц имеется поле с идентификатором, по которому можно понять что находится в данной строке: наименование, характеристика или свойство. Но есть и такие, где находится только одна колонка без идентификаторов. Для дальнейшей работы нужно знать эту информацию, но определить мы это можем только в Excel по группировкам и внешнему виду.

Кусочек таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не-использование экселя обусловлено выгрузкой на сервер, то лучше пойти со стороны какого-нибудь https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel для PHP или http://www.python-excel.org/ в случае с Python. В любом случае - где-то этот файл создаётся и там есть эксель, идти лучше с той стороны.

Не факт, что через ADO будет выдаваться что-то кроме голого текста, без оформления.

Голым SQL придётся городить монструозную конструкцию из IF(), строковых функций.
Лучше сначала подготовить файл в экселе, в идеале вообще переформатировать в итоге на VBA или формулами в структуру вида:

```
Номер  Наименование  Характеристика  Свойство1  Значение  
Номер  Наименование  Характеристика  Свойство2  Значение
```

и проч.

Благодаря автодополнению это будет относительно просто и контролируемо, а дальше уже в таком виде грузить любым удобным методомкидать в промежуточную таблицу, которую уже приводить к нормализованному виду любимым привычным инструментарием.

К сожалению, без реального образца файла, помочь не получится - вчерашняя пересборка astral.lib закончилась с ошибкой.

Comment: К сожалению, нумерация тут только для понимания иерархии. В самом Excel в колонках находится только текст наименования\характеристики\свойства.

Comment: соответственно тогда и ответ - руками довести под подходящей структуры, а потом экспортить. На данный момент тогда информации в принципе не хватает для решения задачи. Чем одна ячейка отличается от другой?

Comment: Чисто визуально в Excel это реализовано с помощью группировки программными средствами и оформлением ячейки. Добавил небольшой кусочек таблицы в вопрос.

Comment: поправил ответ. Пока что сферическая задача в вакууме, предложил альтернативы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Решили править на стороне клиента.